# are temporary files temporal? if so how long?

Tags: go, multipartform-data, temporary-files

I´m building a web app that allows users to upload files < 5MB, and for this I´m using *Request.ParseMultipartForm(5000000)*, but I´m wondering what happens if a funny guy tries to upload a file bigger than 5MB, documentation is not clear enough https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.ParseMultipartForm

> The whole request body is parsed and up to a total of maxMemory bytes of its file parts are stored in memory, with the remainder stored on disk in temporary files

So, how long "temporary files" really means? because it´s a little ambiguous, does that mean that remaining file will be erase after the handler function returns? or does mean that has a lifetime determined? I wouldn´t want my app to crash if some guys try to do this and I run out of disk space.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Temporary files live for the duration of the request. Parsing of the form and the creation of the temp files are handled by the [`mime/multipart`](https://golang.org/pkg/mime/multipart/) package.

When the server finishes the request, it calls [`Form.RemoveAll`](https://golang.org/pkg/mime/multipart/#Form.RemoveAll) to delete any temporary files associated with the form data.

Comment: Is there a way to stop writing in temporary files in first place?

Comment: @JohnBalvinArias Set `maxMemory` so large that everything fits into memory.

Comment: but that would be worse, It´s the same scenario, but now it´s memory

Comment: @JohnBalvinArias: what exactly do you want to do? If you want to read the entire form, memory or temporary files are the only possible destinations.

Comment: I just want to read it from memory, "normal users" would not be even allowed to upload any file > 5MB because of front end, but any hacker can do it and I may be in troubles if I don´t make this in a good way

Comment: If you want to read each part yourself, then use [`MultiPartReader`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.MultipartReader). If you want to limit the request body size altogether, then use [`MaxBytesReader`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#MaxBytesReader)